# LoopJ AndroidAsyncHttp is returning response in OnFailure

Tags: android, android-async-http

i am new to AndroidAsyncHttp.

i created a class httptester :

```
 private static AsyncHttpClient client = new AsyncHttpClient();

    public static void get(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
        client.get(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
    }

    public static void post(String url, RequestParams params, AsyncHttpResponseHandler responseHandler) {
        client.post(getAbsoluteUrl(url), params, responseHandler);
    }

    private static String getAbsoluteUrl(String relativeUrl) {
        return  relativeUrl;
    }
```

and in my activity did the following:

```
RequestParams params = new RequestParams();
        params.put("FTID", HTTPRequestUserAuthentication.AppID);
        params.put("UUID", MainActivity.uuid);
        params.put("TYPE", "11");
        params.put("DateTimeStamp", DateTimeStamp);
        params.put("SDFVersionNb", SDFVersionNb);

        httptester.post(MainActivitySharedPref.GetValue(MyApplication.getContext(), "WebService_URL")+MyApplication.getContext().getResources().getString(R.string.url_get_user_data), params,new JsonHttpResponseHandler() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString) {
                super.onSuccess(statusCode, headers, responseString);

                Log.e(TAG, "sucess: " + responseString);

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(int statusCode, Header[] headers, String responseString, Throwable throwable) {
                Log.e(TAG, "failure: " + responseString);
                Log.e(TAG, "failurecode: " + statusCode);

                super.onFailure(statusCode, headers, responseString, throwable);
            }

        });
```

after calling the client, the correct response is being returned but it is being returned in OnFailure and not in OnSuccess. i also printed the status code in onfailure and it is 200 which supposedly should be OK.

any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you call in your request

```
new JsonHttpResponseHandler()
```

But you need

```
new AsyncHttpResponseHandler()
```